# Access element across multiple hash of hash of arrays

Tags: perl, hash, wait

So I have created a hash of hash of arrays. This data structure (lets call it "amey") is a collection of python tests that i wish to control the execution of.

It looks something like this:

```
'amey'=
    {
        'test_type1' = {
                  'class_test1' => [
                                        'test_1'
                                      ],
                  'class_test2' => [
                                        'test_1',
                                        'test_2'
                                      ],
                  'class_test3' => [
                                        'test_1'
                                  ]
                };
        'test_type2' = {
                  'class_test1' => [
                                     'test_1',
                                     'test_2'
                                   ]
                };
        'test_type3' = {
                   'class_test1' => [
                                          'test_1',
                                          'test_2',
                                          'test_3',
                                          'test_4',
                                          'test_5',
                                          'test_6',
                                          'test_7'
                                        ],
            }
    }
```

The intention is to somehow iterate through this hash and run each test of a type in parallel with a test of another test type. 
*Also knowing which class the test belongs to is important as there are similar named tests. (Example "test_bat")*

So for example:

Start executing the below tests in parallel

```
run test test_type1/class_test1/test_1 &;
run test test_type2/class_test1/test_1 &;
run test test_type3/class_test1/test_1 &;
```

**Wait** for the test of a type to finish running and then start the next of that type.

So for example if `test_type1/class_test1/test_1` completes then start with
`test_type1/class_test2/test_1`.

The number of classes are not the same across each type and nor are the number of tests of each class.

I realize this is kind of a complex requirement (or may be not for the perl monks :)), but would love to hear some suggestions on how I should go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks%3a%3aSuper), create each test in a separate `fork` call and set up dependencies between them.

```
use Forks::Super;
$amey = { ... };

foreach my $class (keys %$amey) {
    foreach my $type (keys %{$amey->{$class}}) {
        my $last_job;
        foreach my $name (keys %{$amey->{$class}{$type}}) {

            my $job = fork {
                name => "$class/$type/$name",
                cmd => "run test $class/$type/$name",
                depend_on => $last_job
            };
            $last_job = "$class/$type/$name";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415186/control-the-length-of-fork-super-queue