# Control the length of Fork Super queue

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

Continuing from my last question [Access element across multiple hash of hash of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413417/access-element-across-multiple-hash-of-hash-of-arrays)

I have this bit of code,

```
use Forks::Super;
foreach my $special_type (keys %test_variables) {
        my $last_job = undef;
        foreach my $test_module (keys %{$test_variables{$special_type}}) {
                foreach my $set_of_tests ($test_variables{$special_type}{$test_module}) {
                        foreach my $test (@$set_of_tests){
                                print "Starting $test\n";
                                my $job = fork {
                                    name => "$special_type/$test_module/$test",
                                    cmd => "nosetests -m $special_type/$test_module/$test",
                                    depend_on => $last_job
                                };
                                $last_job = "$special_type/$test_module/$test";
                                print "Queue last job:$last_job \n\n\n\n";
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

but the length of the queue that is formed seems to be fixed at 1.
So basically only the second process waits for the first one to get completed.

Though I  had imagined/wished that the full queue to be built like 5 waits for 4 , 4 waits for 3 , and 3 wait for 2 and 2 waits for 1.

Question : How do I build the whole queue right at the start?

Comment: Set `$Forks::Super::ON_BUSY = 'queue'` ?

Comment: Under ON_BUSY(https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super#on_busy) i see this  - "If you are using Forks::Super to throttle (see max_proc, $Forks::Super::MAX_PROC) or impose dependencies on (see depend_start, depend_on) background processes, then failure to launch a job should be expected."

Comment: "failure" here means that the job doesn't start right away, which is often what you want when you are throttling the number of jobs or using dependencies. The job can go to a queue, where it will stay until its dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: Got it, that worked. You could enter it as the answer. So that I can mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `$Forks::Super::ON_BUSY` to `queue` or use the module like

```
use Forks::Super ON_BUSY => 'queue';
```

The default setting is `block`, which would stop execution the first time you set up a job with a dependency.

Maybe `queue` should be the default, or at least it should be the default for jobs with dependencies.